# Using Google Translate Java Library, Languages with special chars return question marks

Tags: java, utf-8, google-translate

I have setup a Java program that I made for my apprenticeship project that takes in a JSON file of English strings and outputs a different language JSON file that is defined in the console. Some languages like french and Italian will output with the correct translations whereas Russian or Japanese will output with question marks as seen in the images bellow.

[image: Question Marks]

I had searched around at saw that I needed to get the bytes of my string and then encode that to UTF-8 I did do this but was still getting question marks so I started to use he standard charsets built into Java and tried different ways of encoding/decoding the string I tried this:

[image: Encoding/Decoding]

and this gave me a different output of this : Ð?Ñ?Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ?

```
package com.bis.propertyfiletranslator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.translate.Translate;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.translate.model.TranslationsResource;

public class Translator {

    public static Translate.Translations.List list;
    private static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    private static final Charset ISO = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

    public static void translateJSONMapThroughGoogle(String input, String output, String API, String language,
            List<String> subLists) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

        Translate t = new Translate.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null).setApplicationName("PhoenUX-Google-Translate").build();
        try {

            list = t.new Translations().list(subLists, language).setFormat("text");

            list.setKey(API);

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {

            if (e.getDetails().getMessage().equals("Invalid Value")) {
                System.err.println(
                        "\n Language not currently supported, check the accepted language codes and try again.\n\n Language Requested: "
                                + language);
            } else {
                System.out.println(e.getDetails().getMessage());
            }
        }

        for (TranslationsResource translationsResource : response.getTranslations()) {

            for (String key : JSONFunctions.jsonHashMap.keySet()) {

                JSONFunctions.jsonHashMap.remove(key);

                String value = translationsResource.getTranslatedText();
                String encoded = new String(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

                JSONFunctions.jsonHashMap.put(key, encoded);
                System.out.println(encoded);
                break;
            }
        }

        JSONFunctions.outputTranslationsBackToJson(output);
    }

}
```

So this is using the google cloud library, I added a sysout so I could see the results of what I had tried, so this code should be all you need to replicate it.

I expect the output of "Hello" to be "Привет"(russian) actual output is ???? or Ð?Ñ?Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ? dependent on the encoding I use.

Comment: `String encoded = new String(...)` is dead wrong. Just `put(key, value)`. Note that `System.out.println` will always have problems as the OS encoding might be some Windows ANSI encoding.

Comment: `String(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` is typical cargo-cult codepage-conversion. Java stores `value` using UTF-16 encoding - you convert this UTF-16 to UTF-8 and then reinterpret the bytes as ISO_8859 - which does not make sense. Codepages should be handled in the input and output readers - and `System.out` is not the tool for this job.

Comment: @JoopEggen would it be better if I let the program continue to output straight into the file instead of trying to see the results in the console?

Comment: Yes, with a programmer's editor like Notepad++ or JEdit, that can handle multiple encodings. `Files.write(Paths.get("..."), value.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Comment: @JoopEggen you sir are amazing would you like to submit that as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String encoded = new String(...)` is dead wrong. Just

```
put(key, value):
```

Note that `System.out.println` will always have problems as the OS encoding might be some Windows ANSI encoding. Then it is likely non Unicode-capable - and String contains Unicode.